# Is table partitioning supported on Google Cloud SQL (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, database-partitioning

I've searched on the docs but found nothing about this. Is table partitioning supported on google cloud SQL (MySQL)? If it is supported, is there any drawback to use it? How about using table partition alongside with read replica creation?

If it's not supported, is table partitioning is not necessary to do in cloud SQL? I have several table which growing significantly fast, and now reaching nearly 250M rows. Maybe this is still far from limits but I need to prepare things in advance.

Any info/advice will be appreciated. Thanks before!

Best regards

Comment: MySQL doesn't support out of the box partitioning. You have to manage your distribution key and tables by yourselves.

Comment: MySQL supports Partitioning, but it is mostly useless for performance.  What do you hope that partitioning will help with?  Sharding, on the other hand, is not supported by MySQL; it's DIY.